# Making library with multiple classes, additional pre-existing .a library and other dependencies

Tags: c++, c, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I've done several classes that I'm using in a class called "**LidarPathMapping**". I've been 2 days looking for a solution to make it possible for a person to include the class in his code and use it. I don't want him to need to include the other classes that **LidarPathMapping** depends on and all the other dependencies with which I compile the drivers with which I test my code. My code also depends on a library called **librplidar_sdk.a** and another called **PIGPIO** (it runs in a raspberry pi). I would like that a person that wants to use my code only needs to

```
#include "LidarPathMapping.h"
```

in his code and compile with something like:

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -lLidarPathMapping
```

I don't mind if the person needs to include the libraries I'm using (see in make file) but needing to include every object of each class I've done would defeat the purpose. I have no preference of method, I just want to simplify things for the person that wants to use it.  I would appreciate if also someone could tell me how the library would be used by the user: how to include in .cpp file and in the g++ compilation command.Here is the makefile I've done to compile a driver to test my code:

```
CFLAGS=  -w -Wall

LDIR= /home/pi/Documents/code/cpp/andar/andar/include

LIBS= -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem \
       -lrplidar_sdk -lstdc++ -lpthread -lpigpio -lrt -pthread \
       -lGL -lGLU -lglut

#DEFS = -D USE_OPEN_GL
######################### Objects ###########################

OBJS = objects/LidarPlusServo.o \
        objects/CloudManipulation.o \
        objects/RoverParameters.o \
        objects/csvReader.o \
        objects/Dstar.o \
        objects/LidarPathMapping.o \


######################### Headers ###########################

ANDARHEADERS = andar_include/LidarPlusServo.h \
               andar_include/CloudManipulation.h \
               andar_include/RoverParameters.h \
               csvReader/csvReader.hpp \
               include/Dstar.h \
               andar_include/LidarPathMapping.h \

######################### Source Files ###########################
ANDARSRC = LidarPlusServo.cpp \
               CloudManipulation.cpp \
               RoverParameters.cpp \
               csvReader/csvReader.cpp \
               Dstar.cpp \
               LidarPathMapping.cpp \


######################## Executable ##################################

#Change name here#
#If main file is called "helloWorld.cpp", write "helloWorld"

NAME = driverLidPathMap

$(NAME): $(OBJS) $(NAME).cpp
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(NAME).cpp $(OBJS) \
                     $(LIBS) -L$(LDIR)

####################### Create Objects ########################
objects/LidarPlusServo.o: LidarPlusServo.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS) 
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) LidarPlusServo.cpp

objects/CloudManipulation.o: CloudManipulation.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) CloudManipulation.cpp

objects/RoverParameters.o: RoverParameters.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) RoverParameters.cpp

objects/csvReader.o: csvReader/csvReader.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c  -o $@ $(CFLAGS) csvReader/csvReader.cpp

objects/Dstar.o: Dstar.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c  -o $@ $(CFLAGS) Dstar.cpp

objects/LidarPathMapping.o: LidarPathMapping.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c  -o $@ $(CFLAGS) LidarPathMapping.cpp
```

Comment: Do you want a static library or a shared library?

Comment: Shared would be preferred in terms of performance. I would appreciate if also you could tell me how the library would be used by the user: how to include in .cpp file and in the g++ compilation command. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, here is a useful trick. You have a separate rule for each object:

```
objects/LidarPlusServo.o: LidarPlusServo.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) LidarPlusServo.cpp

objects/CloudManipulation.o: CloudManipulation.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) CloudManipulation.cpp

objects/RoverParameters.o: RoverParameters.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) RoverParameters.cpp

...
```

You are using the automatic variable `$@`, but you can also use `$<` for the first argument in the prerequisite list:

```
objects/LidarPlusServo.o: LidarPlusServo.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

objects/CloudManipulation.o: CloudManipulation.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

objects/RoverParameters.o: RoverParameters.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

...
```

Notice that all of these rules are the same, except for the target and the first prerequisite, which follow a simple rule, `objects/foo.o: foo.cpp`. So you can replace all of these rules with one pattern rule:

```
objects/%.o: %.cpp $(ANDARHEADERS)
    sudo g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

**Now for building and using the library.** I don't know enough about the internals of your source files to know exactly what changes are necessary, but I will give a simple example to show the technique.

Suppose I have three source files, `ant.cpp`, `bee.cpp`, `crocket.cpp`, with their respective header files, Each contains some classes, some of which depend on each other. Now I want to combine them into a shared library, `libInsect.so`, with an associated header file, `Insect.h`, and build an executable `bughunt` that uses it.

`Insect.h` is easy:

```
#include "ant.h"
#include "bee.h"
#include "cricket.h"
```

Now for the makefile:

```
OBJECTS := ant.o bee.o cricket.o

%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC -c $< -o $@

libInsect.so: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^

bughunt: bughunt.cpp libInsect.so
    $(CXX) -L. $< -lInsect -o $@
```

Comment: The compiling has worked fine and an executable is created but when I run the program it returns this error message:

"error while loading shared libraries: <libmylibrary.so>: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have a copy of the .so file in the same directory as the driver.cpp and the makefile. There's also a copy in another folder that I included with -L/path but it still doesn't find the path. I followed the instructions in another post:

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my_library/path.so.something
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ./my_app

still not found

Comment: Try it with the library in the same directory as the executable. (Maybe you already have, I can't tell from your comment.) If that doesn't work, **try something simpler.** Your system is much too complicated. Try `HelloWorld`, then `HelloWorld` with a static library, then with a shared library.

Comment: Thank you Beta, it is working now. I added the library to the /usr/lib folder and now it is working fine. I will make sure to put a command that copies the library to that folder in the make install file. Thank you.